# Plotting graphs using numerical/mathematica method

Tags: real-analysis, numerical-methods, graphing-functions, mathematica

From the [author's equation 13, 14](http://arxiv.org/abs/0910.5922) We can write by inserting V''(A)=0, 
Solving for R we get, 
$$R= \frac{6^{D/4} \sqrt{D}}{\sqrt{-2^{1+\frac{D}{2}} 3^{D/2}+3 2^{1+D} A-3^{1+\frac{D}{2}} A^2}}$$
Now inserting the  V into the article equation (11)$$E= \left(\frac{\pi }{2}\right)^{D/2} R^D V,$$ we get,
$$E= \left(\frac{\pi }{2}\right)^{D/2} \left(-\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^{D/2} A^3+2^{\frac{1}{2} (-4-D)} A^4+A^2 \left(1+\frac{D}{2 R^2}\right)\right) R^D$$
Now inserting the value of R, we get, 
$$E= \left(-\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^{D/2} A^3+2^{\frac{1}{2} (-4-D)} A^4+A^2 \left(1+2^{-1-\frac{D}{2}} 3^{-D/2} \left(-2^{1+\frac{D}{2}} 3^{D/2}+3 2^{1+D} A-3^{1+\frac{D}{2}} A^2\right)\right)\right) \left(\frac{6^{D/4} \sqrt{D}}{\sqrt{-2^{1+\frac{D}{2}} 3^{D/2}+3 2^{1+D} A-3^{1+\frac{D}{2}} A^2}}\right)^D \left(\frac{\pi }{2}\right)^{D/2}$$

For $D= 3$
 we finally get, 
$$E= \frac{27 6^{3/4} \left(-\frac{2}{3} \sqrt{\frac{2}{3}} A^3+\frac{A^4}{8 \sqrt{2}}+A^2 \left(1+\frac{-12 \sqrt{6}+48 A-9 \sqrt{3} A^2}{12 \sqrt{6}}\right)\right) \pi ^{3/2}}{\left(-12 \sqrt{6}+48 A-9 \sqrt{3} A^2\right)^{3/2}} \tag{1}$$
the graph for equation (1) must satisfy the article **[graph (FIG 2)](http://arxiv.org/abs/0910.5922)**

**My graph:**

```
Plot[(27 6^(3/4) (-(2/3) Sqrt[2/3] A^3 + A^4/(8 Sqrt[2]) +A^2 (1 + (-12 Sqrt[6] + 48 A - 9 Sqrt[3] A^2)/( 12 Sqrt[6]))) \[Pi]^(3/2))/(-12 Sqrt[6] + 48 A - 9 Sqrt[3] A^2)^(3/2), {A, 0.5, 2.5}]
```

[image]

**But the author got,**

Output : [image]

Am I doing wrong in simulation?

[Then The author got like this in Fig 3](http://arxiv.org/abs/0910.5922) 
[image]

`

Comment: Maybe you need to substitute 2 for $D$ in your formula? And add a division somewhere?

Comment: I have added 2 for D, but that didn't work.

Comment: The reason you're not getting any output is because you forgot to replace one of the `D`s with a number. However, even if you do this, it doesn't seem to output the answer you want.

Comment: Look, this can't be that hard. Try building up the formula slowly. It does look like you are missing a division sign.

Comment: Ohh, sorry I have eddied my missing, but still it looks different,  what division can make this graph alike with the article?

Comment: The curve you included is not the curve for that equation.  Look carefully at what they have plotted, it is not the solution to Eq 14, they did other stuff to generate the figure, and they spell it out in the paper.

Comment: There's a typo in either the formula or the Mathematica input. If the formula is correct, the * sign between 3 and 2 should be removed.

Comment: @rajb245,Yup,but then which formula they have plotted in the fig:3?
in fig 3, I can see that , they have plotted for A versus R , which represents the equation I gave!!!

Comment: It would help if you described how you arrived at your expression for R. It's not stated explicitly in the article as far as I can see.

Comment: Okay I'm adding that.

Comment: Ok, I deleted my answer, since there apparently was no typo. I get the same expression for E(A) as you do, so they have probably plotted something else, but I don't have the competence/time/patience to decipher the article any further. Good luck!

Comment: "Then substitute the result into Eq. 11 to eliminate R,
yielding energy as a function only of A."  They take your result and plug it into the energy to get $E(A)$, energy as a function of $A$.  Then they minimized this energy and found a numerical value and called it $E_\infty$.  They then claim that there are other combinations of $(A,R)$ that achieve the same energy.  I'm honestly not sure on the details since I haven't studied the paper closely, but it seems to make sense that it's possible to find curves that satisfy $E(A,R)=E_{\infty}$. Solutions to that are is what they plotted.

Comment: You're almost there, your plot is minimized at $A \approx 0.982349$.  Now plug that into the expression of $E$ and you get the $E_\infty$ that the authors got!

Comment: I have got 5.36 but the authour got 37.69 :O ?

Comment: @ComplexGuy In your first plot, you have the wrong code. In the second term inside the root it says `3*2^(1 + 2)*A` while it should say `32^(1 + 2)*A`.

Comment: Sorry forgot to edit, yup I got little mistake but the correction didn't give identical results.

Comment: Actually, What I need to get is identical with the article figure $2, 2 , 4$.
They have found the value of R from equation (14) then V and R has been inserted into equation (11), this equation gives the plot (2), then they got Fig(3) and fig(4) with several curves.
I'm confused that how they got several curves !

Comment: @pragabha,  dartmouth.edu/~dpsicilia/Thesis.pdf this thesis is relted to this question.

Comment: Check this please http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/430417/plotting-diagram-without-counting-nodes.
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/434298/finding-potential-with-dimensions-terms

Comment: @pragabha, you got it?

Comment: @pragabha, I have reedited now, can you look it now please?

Comment: Try adding `PlotRange -> {0, 100}` to your plot and see if it still looks different.

Comment: Are you mentioning about the value of A ?

Comment: Can you please do the graph, I have tried several times :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mathematica is more powerful that you give it credit for.  You don't have to define any quantities explicitly.  It is much more efficient to keep things in symbolic terms and numerically substitute values only when you need them.  The below works for $d=3$ and gives results consistent with the paper.

Briefly:

1. Define the function $V(A)=\frac{A^4}{2^{\frac{d+4}{2}}}-A^3 \left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^{d/2}+A^2 \left(\frac{d}{2 R^2}+1\right);$
2. Calculate the solution to $V''(A)=0$, take the second $R$ solution
3. Plug that $R$ into $E(A)=\left(\frac{\pi }{2}\right)^{d/2} V(A) R^d$ and plot
4. Solve $E'(A)=0$, pick the third solution and call the minimum value $E_\infty$
5. Solve $\left(\frac{\pi }{2}\right)^{d/2} V(A) R^d=E_\infty$ for $R$ as a function of $A$ (taking the third solution); this is the locus of points that attain the energy $E_\infty$

To get the right answers you have to simply select the "right" solution that Mathematica spits out when solving the various equations.  The code for $d=3$ appears below and recreates the paper results.

```
(*Change this to 2 or 3*)
d = 3;
(*Define the potential*)
V[A_] := (1 + d/(2 R^2)) A^2 - (2/3)^(d/2) A^3 + A^4/2^((d + 4)/2);
(*Find the energy*)
Energy[A_] := 
  Evaluate[(\[Pi]/2)^(d/2) R^d V[A] /. Solve[V''[A] == 0, R][[2]]];
Plot[Energy[A], {A, 0, 2.5}, PlotRange -> {0, 100}]
(*This is the minimum energy, matches article for d=2 and d=3*)
NSolve[D[Energy[A], A] == 0, A][[3]]
Einf = Energy[A] /. NSolve[D[Energy[A], A] == 0, A][[3]]
Plot[R /. NSolve[(\[Pi]/2)^(d/2) R^d V[A] == Einf, R][[3]], {A, 0, 
  2.5}, PlotRange -> {0, 6}]
```

And the plots are

[image: Energy as function of amplitude]
[image: R and amplitude points that attain the minimum energy]

Comment: Wow, you did it. thanks, you used [[2]]] and  [[3]]], are these referring dimension d=2 and d= 3 ? 
And  how do we locate the attractor point with drawing multiple curves?

They have said also in three dimensions they didn't predict the attractor point so they guessed, How the guess would be ?

Comment: The various solve functions in Mathematica will generally output multiple results because the equations can have multiple solutions.  The "[[2]]" and "[[3]]" select the correct one out of the group of solutions.  I found these by separating the real answers from the imaginary ones.

Comment: So, can you please merge these results For Fig:3?

Comment: For the multiple curves, the one I present is the "thin solid line" from Figure 4.  The thick solid lines are the set of points that satisfy $\omega_\text{gap}=\Gamma_\text{lin}$.  What have you tried to do in order to calculate this curve?  Where are you stuck?  What progress have you made?

Comment: I got you how you plotted the graph for d=3 in Fig:4 and in the following way  I have done for d=2. But my query is, **I see in the Fig is thick, thin and dashed curve, how do I trace them out? are these curve same code you given are I will need to formulate more code and then combine?**

Comment: Did you try for the other curves?
How will we separate thick line and thin line? 
Is it from the (14) equation that is not included the energy 37.69 ?

Comment: You will need to formulate more code and combine.  The thick solid line is the curve that solves equation $(10)$ ("The thick solid line represents the locus of points satisfying the condition $\omega_\text{gap}= \Gamma_\text{lin}$ ").  They tell you how to get the other curves on page four, top of the right column.  

Since this question is closed, try and interpret what's written in the text of the paper to make the plots.  The formulas and information is all there.  If you have specific questions about the mathematics, create a new question and post a link here.  I will take a look then.

Comment: Please, see the question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/440700/graph-for-oscillons-decay

Answer (score 1):

Look at your function in a much more simple way:

$$R(A) = \frac{\sqrt{12}}{\sqrt{24 A - 9 A^2-12}}$$

for $D=2$.  The function should have a horizontal tangent when the derivative of the radicand is zero:

$$\frac{d}{dA} (24 A - 9 A^2-12) = 0 \implies A = \frac{4}{3}$$

which seems to agree with your result.  Also, $R$ blows up when the denominator goes to zero, or when $A=2$ and $A=2/3$, which also agrees with your plot.  So far, I'd say your plot looks good.

Comment: Got you, then which formula they have plotted in the fig:3?

Comment: @ComplexGuy: not obvious to me.